# Get all Sites Defined in ServiceDefinition for Azure

Tags: azure

We can define many sites in `ServiceDefinition.csdef`

I want to know how to get the list programely. I played around `RoleEnvironment` class but cannot get a clue. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most compatibility (and not to rely on undocumented implementation details that can change), you should just use the same method that you would use on premises.  Use `Microsoft.Web.Administration` assembly and the `ServerManager` class.  It contains a Sites collection with all the details you need.

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{ 
    var sites = serverManager.Sites; 
    foreach (Site site in sites) 
        Console.WriteLine(site.Name); // This will return the WebSite name
}
```

Comment: yes, you can check if the left `site.name` is `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id` to get all sites

Answer (score 3):

The solution is similar to the approach for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497202/plugin-subdirectory-in-azure-deployment/8501182#8501182).

You can get the list of local sites by something similar to:

```
public IEnumerable<string> WebSiteDirectories
        {
            get
            {
                string roleRootDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RdRoleRoot");
                string appRootDir = (RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated) ? Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) : roleRootDir;

                XDocument roleModelDoc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(roleRootDir, "RoleModel.xml"));

                var siteElements = roleModelDoc.Root.Element(_roleModelNs + "Sites").Elements(_roleModelNs + "Site");

                return
                    from siteElement in siteElements
                    where siteElement.Attribute("name") != null
                            && siteElement.Attribute("name").Value == "Web"
                            && siteElement.Attribute("physicalDirectory") != null
                    select Path.Combine(appRootDir, siteElement.Attribute("physicalDirectory").Value);
            }
        }
```

Where the _roleModelNs variable is defined as follows:

```
private readonly XNamespace _roleModelNs = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition";
```

This will give you the full path. But as you can see it is just reading an XML file, so you can get the hostHeaders also.

You can safely use this approach as the RoleModel.xml file is bound to the SDK version. So the only possible way to break this functionality is if a new SDK introduces breaking changes in this file. Which I doubt to happen. But in case it happens, you can easily check the new XML structure and alter your code.

Comment: Be careful.  This file does change and might even go away.  File is fun to poke around in, but wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for your answer. Where were you when (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497202/plugin-subdirectory-in-azure-deployment/8501182#8501182) was asked :)

Comment: afaik this part could not work as expected:

"where siteElement.Attribute("name") != null && siteElement.Attribute("name").Value == "Web" && siteElement.Attribute("physicalDirectory") != null"

current SDK forces that all sites should have different names, and "Web" is just single "Well-known" name that could be processed without explicit physicalDirectory attribute.

Comment: And I explicitly stated "So the only possible way to break this functionality is if a new SDK introduces breaking changes in this file.". I am well aware that this is SDK bound approach and I expressed it.

Comment: If you put 2 websites in single webrole - you should have different names for it. So provided "where" condition will fail at least 2 times isn't it? Points of failure:
1. Site with @ name="Web" could have no @ physicalDirectory specified - its some kind "well known" and @ physicalDirectory can be ommited. So "@ physicalDirectory!= null" part will fail.
2. If anyone put more than one site to single WebRole - all other sites should have different @ name - therefore @ name=="Web" check will fail. 2 sites with one named "web" and ommited @ physDir - looks pretty common scenario, isn't it ?

Comment: in prev comment @ stands for attribute.
If I'm wrong with latest statements about conditions - please could you  clarify where exactly I misunderstand RoleModel.xml generated structure ?

PS: described behaviour applied to current SDKs, not talking about any future "broken-changes" versions.